# How come I'm User1804?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I notice I'm called User1804 here, but I have a regular username ( glenatron ) on all the other SE sites I belong to.

Is this something odd going on with the conversion? Is there a way I can change this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When we imported Share Point Overflow, we forced associations for existing accounts but we *didn't* copy profiles.

This is because we can't tell which profile a user would consider their "main" one*.

You can copy from any other site in the network via a button on your user profile's account tab.
[image]

So, for instance, to copy your Programmer's profile [go here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/4027/glenatron?tab=accounts) and click the "Copy" button.

Meta accounts are sync'd periodically, so there will be a slight delay there too.

<sub>*This is kind of a special case, since we had accounts with non-empty profiles due to the import.  Normally we'd just copy the profile from your oldest account, but since its irreversible...</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I think if you log out of this site, then log into another site with that account, then come back to this site and log in using the same OpenID method or whatever it should associate your account with this site to the rest of your accounts.