# Odd login/authentication

Tags: support, bug

I've noticed that on most SE sites, I've got `▾dwwilson66 2168 | review | chat | meta | about | faq` just the the left of the search box in the upper right corner (highlighted)

[image]

However, not on the SharePoint or SPMeta SE sites. There's just ~nothing~. 
[image].

I generally use the links here to navigate between other SE sites quickly and easily, and to tell if I'm online for purposes of posting. While this link list is usually my indicator that I'm logged in, I can still post to forums on both SP and SPMeta, even though there IS no visual indicator that I'm online.

I found [this Q&A](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/how-come-im-user1804), and I'm not sure if this is the same problem (it sounds close), but I've tried the login/logout, and while I can't find any links to copy my profile to SharePoint (as noted in the above link), I did find the link to "copy to ALL SE accounts" and used that. Still no luck. Has this ever been resolved? Is there a new fix/workaround?

Comment: So what do you see instead of your normal links? Perhaps it is logging you into a dupe account? Do you have a question you posted under the other account?

Comment: I'll post screenshots.

Comment: Woah! What browser are you using? Have you tried doing a CTRL+F5 to refresh?

Comment: IE8 & I refresh/restart ~lots~. I also clear cache and cookies etc.,  when I close out. I've also noticed this behavior in Chrome. IE8 & Chrome are running on Win7-64Bit, also on Chrome with XP SP3, 32bit. IE8 connects from my worksite, the two Chrome machines are my home, XP is my laptop and that travels with me a lot. Different ISPs; bandwidth, firewalls, etc., but the behavior is consistent. ONLY on sharepoint, none of the other dozen or so SE sites I use. Does that help? Furthur obfuscate? Both?

Comment: This is happening to me too!